# Scaling a web app based on Laravel 3

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, laravel

I'm writing my first web application using the PHP framework [Laravel](http://laravel.com) and a MySQL database. The application is quite image heavy with users likly to typically have 1 GB or more of images hosted by me. Images will be stored in the server's file system with a file reference stored in the database.

I'm just thinking ahead as I code because the application will initially be hosted on my InMoting VPS system to start with but (hopefully) will ultimately outgrow this.

Is there anything I should be doing at this early stage to make sure that the application could be scaled?

Comment: "...say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the easiest and best thing to do right now is move all of your users images over to a CDN like Rackspace cloud files or similar. This way if/when you upgrade the framework, change servers, add new ones, etc most of your physical files are located somewhere else...in addition to having all of the benefits of a CDN network. Besides that I wouldn't worry about over optimizing too much.

Comment: Wow, Rackspace cloud files looks perfect. Thanks for the tip.